# lead programm through second network adapter

Tags: shell-script, networking

I am using Debian (without GUI) and I am trying to get a sh script/file through my second network adapter - but I don't know how.

I read a few articles I found but they end up breaking my network and I have to restart my Server or they just don't work I am still kind of a beginner here.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What do you mean by *"get a sh script/file through my second network adapter"*. Do you want to download a file by you cannot get internet connection with your new network adapter? Or do you want your shell script uses the network interface provided by your network adapter?

Comment: my general question is basically: "Can I get my sh program to go through my second adapter" because by default it chooses my first adapter (ens3 is my first adapter and ens:1 is my second one)

Comment: I think this is related to namespaces. Try this: `sudo firejail --noprofile --net=ens1 ./your_shell_script` (install firejail if fget `firejail: command not found`)

Comment: I've tested with shell script by using ping and did not work as expected. So maybe don't work for you too.

Comment: I will try it in my VM @ work and test if it works

Comment: @AiriTanaka What does "to go through an adapter" mean for a program? This is not a combination of words that makes a lot of sense to me, sadly, but also, English is not my first language… So if you could explain it without using variations of "to go through", but specify what exactly has to happen where, and what your network adapter has to do with it, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Docker I was able to solve my problem (-p XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT) Thank you Edgar for trying to help me and I wish everyone a g'day